# Why doesn't `in` search the values when the Series contains strings

Tags: python, pandas, contains, series

It's probably very basic but why does it seem like `in` doesn't work for `Series` containing objects or strings?

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> s = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> 'a' in s
False
>>> 'a' in s.astype('S1')
False
```

The `Series.__contains__` documentation is rather sparse:

```
[In 1]: s.__contains__?
Signature: s.__contains__(key)
Docstring: True if the key is in the info axis
File:      c:\...\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py
Type:      method
```

My first thought was that `in` only checks the "index":

```
>>> 1 in s
True
```

But then: Why does it (seem to) work with other types:

```
>>> 1.2 in pd.Series([1.3, 1.2])
True

>>> 1 in pd.Series([1.3, 1.2])  # also works for index
True
```

---

I'm not interested in working solutions. I know I can simply use `whatever in s.values` or `np.any(s.eq(whatever))`. I would like to know **why** it behaves that way (or am I missing something?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It behaves that way because a Series is more like an OrderedDict than a list.

Just like `1 in {0: 5, 1: 10}` is True, so is `1 in pd.Series([5, 10])`, because the index is `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2, step=1)`, and the index elements are like the keys.

I see why the case of

```
>>> 1.2 in pd.Series([1.3, 1.2])
True
```

could be a little confusing, but it's just a coincidence based on the numbers you've chosen -- the 1.2 is coerced to an int before comparison with either a RangeIndex or an Int64Index, so you're really asking `1 in ser.index`.  Personally I don't like this behaviour, but that's what it's doing.

```
>>> 1.9 in pd.Series([1.3, 1.2])
True
>>> 1.2 in pd.Series([1.3, 1.2], index=[10, 20])
False
```

---

To make the coercion even more obvious:

```
In [54]: np.inf in pd.Series([1.3, 1.2])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-b069ecc5baf6> in <module>()
----> 1 np.inf in pd.Series([1.3, 1.2])

[...]
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.__contains__ (pandas/_libs/index.c:3924)()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.__contains__ (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:13569)()

OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer
```